# How to rediredt the stdout in a text window - c programming

Tags: c, console, stdout, gtk3

I would like to realize in GTK3 a text window where to redirect the stdout using the c language.
Could you help me with suggestions about how to start.
Thank you.

Comment: Where you redirect `stdout` to where?

Comment: a widget able to shows text

Comment: This might help you: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2006-February/msg00040.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you'll need to do is write GTK code that reads from a named pipe and writes to the text box, and when you start your other c code (assuming you're starting it from a shell command), redirect stdout to the named pipe.